# Caddy Prerender io integration not working

Tags: javascript, server, reverse-proxy, prerender, caddy

I have been trying to connect my Vue.js application to Prerender.io so that the SEO bots can crawl and index my pages. I uploaded the sitemap for my website and created an integration with Caddy that is based on the nginx integration. When I run a test of my integration, in chrome, I get a 404 not found error.

here is my code from the integration that I produced.

```
mywebsite.com {
        @prerender {
                header_regexp User-Agent "(bot|googlebot|yahoo!\ slurp|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest\/0\.|developers.google.com\/\+\/web\/snippet|slackbot|vkshare|w3c_validator|redditbot|applebot|whatsapp|flipboard|tumblr|bitlybot|skypeuripreview|nuzzel|discordbot|google\ page\ speed|qwantify|pinterestbot|bitrix\ link\ preview|xing-contenttabreceiver|chrome-lighthouse|telegrambot|google-inspectiontool|petalbot)"
                not path_regexp filetypes /\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|eot)$/
        }
        reverse_proxy @prerender https://service.prerender.io {
                header_up X-Prerender-Token "Prerender-Token-Here"
                header_down Cache-Control "private,max-age=600,must-revalidate"
        }
        reverse_proxy /api* :3000
        @notAPI {
                not {
                        path /api*
                }
                file {
                        try_files {path} {path}/ /index.html
                }
        }
        rewrite @notAPI {http.matchers.file.relative}
        root * path/to/prod
        file_server {
                precompressed zstd br gzip
        }
        header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000"
}
```

Here is the nginx integration that I based the above off of:

```
# Change YOUR_TOKEN to your prerender token
# Change example.com (server_name) to your website url
# Change /path/to/your/root to the correct value

worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile           on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    map $http_user_agent $prerender_ua {
        default       0;
        "~*Prerender" 0;

        "~*googlebot"                               1;
        "~*yahoo!\ slurp"                           1;
        "~*bingbot"                                 1;
        "~*yandex"                                  1;
        "~*baiduspider"                             1;
        "~*facebookexternalhit"                     1;
        "~*twitterbot"                              1;
        "~*rogerbot"                                1;
        "~*linkedinbot"                             1;
        "~*embedly"                                 1;
        "~*quora\ link\ preview"                    1;
        "~*showyoubot"                              1;
        "~*outbrain"                                1;
        "~*pinterest\/0\."                          1;
        "~*developers.google.com\/\+\/web\/snippet" 1;
        "~*slackbot"                                1;
        "~*vkshare"                                 1;
        "~*w3c_validator"                           1;
        "~*redditbot"                               1;
        "~*applebot"                                1;
        "~*whatsapp"                                1;
        "~*flipboard"                               1;
        "~*tumblr"                                  1;
        "~*bitlybot"                                1;
        "~*skypeuripreview"                         1;
        "~*nuzzel"                                  1;
        "~*discordbot"                              1;
        "~*google\ page\ speed"                     1;
        "~*qwantify"                                1;
        "~*pinterestbot"                            1;
        "~*bitrix\ link\ preview"                   1;
        "~*xing-contenttabreceiver"                 1;
        "~*chrome-lighthouse"                       1;
        "~*telegrambot"                             1;
        "~*google-inspectiontool"                   1;
        "~*petalbot"                                1;
    }

    map $args $prerender_args {
        default $prerender_ua;
        "~(^|&)_escaped_fragment_=" 1;
    }

    map $http_x_prerender $x_prerender {
        default $prerender_args;
        "1"     0;
    }

    map $uri $prerender {
        default $x_prerender;
        "~*\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|woff2|svg|eot)" 0;
    }

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.com;
        root   /path/to/your/root;

        location / {

            if ($prerender = 1) {
                rewrite (.*) /prerenderio last;
            }
            try_files $uri /index.html = 404;
        }

        location /prerenderio {
            if ($prerender = 0) {
                return 404;
            }

            proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOUR_TOKEN;

            proxy_hide_header Cache-Control;
            add_header Cache-Control "private,max-age=600,must-revalidate";

            #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
            resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;
            set $prerender_host "service.prerender.io";
            proxy_pass https://$prerender_host;
            rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the test on Chrome using the User Agent changer under the Network conditions tab, I get a Not Found 404 error. What I should receive is the prerendered page sent from prerender.io.

When I contacted Prerender.io support and they said they can't help me since they don't have an official maintained middleware integration with Caddy. Please help!

Comment: the URL for the website that isn't working is https://justclicksolar.com.